# What is the best way to restart a node.js server after a change is made to its application script

Tags: node.js

So, I'm in the process of learning node, and am finding that for testing, I have to kill the running instance of node, then start it up again with the new application code for the server.  So, I first execute my node server like this:  `node myapp.js`.

Then, I notice something isn't working right, or I want to add some new code to myapp.js.  I go into Process Explorer (I'm running node on a Windows box), and kill the node.exe process, and then upload the new myapp.js file with the changes.  Then I do `node myapp.js` to start it again to test again.

There has got to be an easier way to do this.  I typed in `node --help` but there are too many flags listed to see if there is some kind of restart mechanism similar to apache on linux like: `httpd -k restart`.  Is there a kind of "graceful" restart with node?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out nodemon. Install it using `npm install nodemon`, after that simply use `nodemon server.js` if server.js is the file you're working on.

Comment: This worked, and am sure node-supervisor will also work @Bartek.

Answer (score 1):

Use [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor)

Comment: This looks like the same thing and nodemon, and will probably do the trick just fine, too.